# On page load start view at right position of container, but keep text ltr

Tags: html, css

I want the behaviour of `direction: rtl` but want to keep the text as it would be in `direction: ltr`.

So I have a list:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Item 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Item 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The result should be:
Item1 Item2 Item3

But starting at right scroll position. So if I don't have enough space, I would see Item3 and Item2.

I've tried the following with no luck:
http://jsfiddle.net/v2e6o1fb/1/

Is there any chance to do this with CSS? And if not, how would I go in JS?

Comment: Remove width in wrapper class

Comment: @RajaRamachandran
Same result if I remove it and resize body to check which item is shown.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v2e6o1fb/14/